# When is it the right time to take measurements of an element rendered by react?

Tags: reactjs

consider this code

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   element = null;
   componentDidMount() {
       if (this.element === null) return;
       console.log(this.element.clientHeight); // <-- gives inconsistent results
   }
   render() {
       return <div className="my-container">
            <div className="my-content"
                 ref={self => this.element = self}>Hey</div>
       </div>;
   }
}
```

and styles

```
 .my-container { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
 .my-content {
     position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
 }
```

problem is that i am not always getting `clientHeight === 100`

how can i get consistent measurements?

UPDATE:

with `window.requestAnimationFrame` it gives more consistent (yet not always) results

```
   componentDidMount() {
       if (this.element === null) return;
       window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
           console.log(this.element.clientHeight); // <-- better, but still inconsistent at times
       });
   }
```

Comment: No, it gives consistent results, as expected https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tjhqzc?file=index.tsx . The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: but it's a lot of work to narrow it down

Comment: But somebody has to do this work, and it's asker's responsibility. You should know already how SO works, considering your rep. It's impossible to answer the question without knowing the circumstances under which the problem occurs.

Comment: but this work we are talking about is 87% of the question, with that said what does SO do to reduce this number?

Comment: and i guess my hope was to hear from someone who already dealt with this problem and has a solution handy

Comment: *what does SO do to reduce this number?* - SO enforces off-topic questions (which this question currently is) to be closed, this helps users to not waste their time on poorly asked questions and focus on quality ones. I happened to find an answer to my own question a lot of times when trying to create MCVE, this happens. Sometimes there's a way to give a proper answer even for lazy question, but this is not the case. As it was shown, the behaviour you're describing cannot be replicated. Your code differs from the one you've posted in some unknown way that affects this behavior.

Comment: same can be said about your repo hosted in very certain sandbox full of its own specifics, far not all questions are well formed due to lack of basic knowledge, lack of details of understanding of black box components, etc, so you think you can draw a line? i wish i had your certainty

Comment: Asking a good question requires to know half an answer. Yes, that's the catch. Regarding your question, componentDidMount is the right place to do that for the code you've posted. There is no right time and place to do that for arbitrary component that changes its dimensions dynamically/asynchronously (this is specific to any JS framework, not just React). In order to get this opportunity, a component should provide a way to notify a parent that it was rendered to initial state.

Comment: the example is pretty close to the real situation with exception of: all sorts of loaders: requirejs, styles, etc.; version of react; host component; circumstances where this code is used; there is no way i can reproduce is in its native setup without bringing tons of dependencies (not sure even how i can do it here), but more importantly each question has a price at which it is worth being answered, again if anyone had seen anything similar the price is low, you are not that person, you are welcome to go close some newbie questions that pops up in hundreds at SO every second

Comment: i appreciate your repo, it rules out some guess work

Comment: The rules are same for SO newbies and experts. Btw, you could also try to use `ref` as 'the right time', `<div className="my-content" ref={self => this.takeMeasurements(self)}>Hey</div>`. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it looks like styles are not fully applied to DOM at the time of measurements / reflow hasn't happened, with delayed measuring i got pretty workable results, wish there was a handler on a DOM node that said it's ready

Comment: Well, you can spy on DOM but that's discouraged, also still may not work. The real problem here is why styles are applied asynchronously. If this is caused by lazy loaded css, loading process could be tracked, or you could postpone the first measurement until window `load` event.